# react-native android - ListView progressive rendering

Tags: react-native

I am playing with the `<ListView>` component. My screen is capable of displaying 9 rows from a data set of 32. However I see in the console that the ListView component triggers the `renderRow` function 32 times (basically it seems to render in the background all the items of my data set).

I was expecting that the function would be triggered only when a new row appears on screen.

Is this a normal behavior?

Or is there an option that can specify under what conditions the `renderRow` function should be triggered?

Thanks for your suggestions.
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In fact the rows of the list are build ahead of time so that the scroll of the list remains as smooth as possible.

The default value (in version 0.1.8) is 1000 pixels.

[image]

My list items were 20px high. 32 items * 20px = 640px. The first ten were rendered and visible anyway so there were remaining 440px to be rendered.

You can override this default setting by using the `scrollRenderAheadDistance` attribute of `<ListView>` in order to optimize your rendering if needed.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#scrollrenderaheaddistance

Comment: So on your example here... you set DEFAULT_SCROLL_RENDER_AHEAD to 440 ?
Could you explain a bit more what you try and what your final result for best performance was?
I currently have a list of 980 Items where each has an height of 57px.

Which size would you recommend for ...RENDER_AHEAD?

Comment: Hi @suther,
In principle you have to render as few items as possible ahead of time but enough still so that your user has a good experience. You probably shouldn't change this default value unless you test extensively. If you have performance issues you should try higher rows (resulting in less pre-rendered items) or a less complex design. Hope it helps. :)